# how to get updated table values while the php page is running

Tags: javascript, php

I'm developing a website using php. I have some problems. I want to know know how to get modified table values while running the php page without refreshing the page.

```
<html>
<?php
function fun_get_user_name() {
    $host_name = "localhost";
    $db_user_name = "root";
    $password = "";

    $database_name = "database_name";
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $db_user_name, $password, $database_name);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $output = "";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output = $output."<br/>"..$row[0];
    }
}
?>
<script>
function js_function() {
    result = "<?php echo fun_get_user_name; ?>";
    document.getElementById('div_body_users').innerHTML = result;
}
window.setInterval(function() {
    js_function();
}, 1000);
</script>

<body>
    <div id="div_body_users">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

when I made a change in phpmyadmin table the change didn't affect the page. But I expected the updated table.

Comment: yes you can do that with the help of `ajax` method

Comment: how can I do it ?

Comment: Are you expecting that when you update your table data that the page will update?

Comment: when I update the table in phpmyadmin manually the updation should affect the page also without reloading.

Comment: Please check I posted answer. you have to use Ajax Along with setInterval.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a tool to manage DB, it is not a DB itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB.

Comment: Take a look at [socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Answer (score 0):

So move the fun_get_user_name to another file and then in a setInterval do a  n ajax call to that file.

```
$.get( "users.php", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

For more info on ajax request look at this link
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

On user.php you just need to add fun_get_user_name

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with using ajax, here changed with your ajax url and database connection details.

```
      <html>
      <?php
      function fun_get_user_name()
      {
          $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "root";
            $dbname = "test";

            // Create connection
          $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                          // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                              echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. "<br>";
                      }
                   } else {
                              echo "0 results";
               }


      }
      if($_GET['ajax']==1){
       $data=fun_get_user_name();

       echo $data;
       exit(0);

      }
      ?>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

      setInterval(js_function,1000);

       function js_function()
       {         
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/test2/test.php?ajax=1",
            data: '',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {  
                 document.getElementById('div_body_users').innerHTML=result;
            }
        });

       }

      });
      </script>
      <body>
      <div id="div_body_users">
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You for update page without page refresh you have to use AJAX along with setInterval function.
Please check below link
https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ajax_intro.asp